# SQL query to do row by row comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table:

```
        opendt        enddt         Id
        ------------------------------
        2013-01-20    2013-02-20    1
        2013-02-20    2014-02-06    1
        2013-02-28    NULL          1
```

Ideally for record #2 we should have `enddt = 2013-02-28` but instead it is `2014-02-06` by mistake. I want to find such records where `enddt` is not equal to next row `opendt` for same `ID`. I know I can try finding this by using `temp` tables. Is there is a way to do this without `temp` table? SQL 2012

Comment: yes! wait i am writing SQL

Comment: did you do any thing?

Comment: what SQL Server Version u using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using SQL Server 2012, so I would recommend using `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(opendt) over (partition by id order by opendt) as next_opendt
      from table t
     ) t
where next_opendt <> enddt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
;With CTE as 
    (
        Select *,row_number() over (partition by id order by opendt asc) as rNo from myTable as t1
    )
    select * from CTE as a
    left join CTE as b on a.rNo =b.rNo + 1 and a.id=b.id
    where b.opendt <> a.enddt
```

Comment: One mistake corrected, Thanks! Not infront of SQl server right now. Still any mistake,please correct me.

Comment: I think you also need to join by ID, otherwise, the last record of id=1 will compare to the first record of id=2...

Comment: Corrected, I think no need of join on ID. Syntax corrected, ID removed from Order by also.

Comment: That now seems quite wrong - You have to compare within the same ID, you can't just order by date, no??

Comment: It is better to ask user who has asked question. It depend on whether date is partitioned for each ID or not. What you are saying might also be correct, but it can be decided by user only!

Comment: From the original question: "I want to find such records where enddt is not equal to next row opendt for same ID"

Comment: Oh! Great. Thank you friend. Ans Corrected.

Comment: Perfect!! - Nice solution, BTW! +1

Comment: please remove my output which i added to the question

Comment: No error, I imagine.  It is just not finding the right matches.  Stare a bit longer at the code and you might spot the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I trying to use non CTE way to do this. I have use subqueries and I have mark them in my code. I am not sure if it best way. This answer is a database agnostic.

**This query help us to select data for updating -**

```
select ini.id, 
ini.maxend as opendt, 
fin.opendt as enddt
from
(
select id, MAX(opendt) maxend
from mytable
where enddt is not null
group by id
) as ini -- subquery 1
inner join
(
select id, opendt
from mytable
where enddt is null
) as fin -- subquery 2
on ini.id = fin.id
```

**Now we will use above query to update main tables -**

The generic query for updating from such selects is like this -

```
update t1
set
t1.enddt = t2.enddt
from mytable as t1
inner join (Something) as t2 -- something is a table or select
on (some-condition)
where (some-column = whatever)
```

**This is the final result -**

```
update t1
set
t1.enddt = t2.enddt
--select *
from mytable as t1
inner join 
(
select ini.id, 
ini.maxend as opendt, 
fin.opendt as enddt
from
(
select id, MAX(opendt) maxend
from mytable
where enddt is not null
group by id
) as ini -- subquery 1
inner join
(
select id, opendt
from mytable
where enddt is null
) as fin -- subquery 2
on ini.id = fin.id
) as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
and t1.opendt = t2.opendt
```

**Sample table and rows -**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable](
    [opendt] [date] NULL,
    [enddt] [date] NULL,
    [id] [int] NULL
)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[mytable] ([opendt], [enddt], [id]) 
VALUES (CAST(0xA7360B00 AS Date), CAST(0xC6360B00 AS Date), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[mytable] ([opendt], [enddt], [id]) 
VALUES (CAST(0xC6360B00 AS Date), CAST(0x25380B00 AS Date), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[mytable] ([opendt], [enddt], [id]) 
VALUES (CAST(0xCE360B00 AS Date), NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[mytable] ([opendt], [enddt], [id]) 
VALUES (CAST(0x49370B00 AS Date), CAST(0x4D370B00 AS Date), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[mytable] ([opendt], [enddt], [id]) 
VALUES (CAST(0x4D370B00 AS Date), CAST(0x50370B00 AS Date), 2)
INSERT [dbo].[mytable] ([opendt], [enddt], [id]) 
VALUES (CAST(0x57370B00 AS Date), NULL, 2)
```